# Writing unit test for a method containing RxJava's throttleLast operator

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I've got a method that I'd like to test that looks something like this:

```
 private Disposable getStuff(){
    return Observable
            .combineLatest(
                    repoOne.getStuff(),
                    repoTwo.getOtherStuff(),
                    session.getSomethingElse(),
                    session.getOtherSomethingElse(),
                    (a, b, c, d) -> new Stuff.Builder()
                            .stuff(a)
                            .stuffB(b)
                            .stuffC(c)
                            .stuffD(d)
                            .build())
            .throttleLast(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe(this::populateStuff, this::showError);
}
```

I'm trying to test this method but it doesn't get passed `throttleLast`. I've tried it mostly by applying a `TestScheduler`, but didn't get anywhere with it. For example I've tried:

```
<...>
    .throttleLast(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,mTestScheduler)
<...>
```

Then when I call the method, I advance the time:

```
    mCompositeDisposable.add(getStuff());
    mTestScheduler.advanceTimeTo(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    mTestScheduler.advanceTimeTo(505, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But that does nothing, i.e. `populateStuff` or `showError` is still not called. I'm probably using the `TestScheduler` incorrectly, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to test the observer chain without the `throttleLast()`? More specifically, are you able to test the operation of `combineLatest()`? Since you aren't testing the RxJava library, it may be sufficient to unit test the pieces where there is a possibility of error.

Comment: @BobDalgleish yeah my test only stopped working once I added `throttleLast`. But I wanted to test `onNext` and `onError` flows as well, based on the result of `combineLatest`. Might get quite tricky to try to separate throttling out...

Comment: Hmmm. Does your unit test work, with the test scheduler in place, if you remove the `subscribeOn()`/`observeOn()` pair?

Comment: Works without `throttleLast`, doesn't work with throttling.

Comment: Weirdly, looking at the `TestScheduler` in debug, the counter advances as expected after I advance the time, however, the queue size is 0. So my `throttleLast` doesn't get added to that scheduler? Not sure

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not really sure why this is not working, so any explanation will definitely help. However, as a fix I have replaced `throttleLast` with `sample`:

```
.sample(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true)
```

From my understanding `throttleLast` is calling `sample` with `emitLast` argument set to false. Logically, I do want to emit the last item anyway, so for me the change is beneficial. However, not really sure how the chain behaves in the unit tests using `TestScheduler`s to make it skip any emission.